# create Scheduled Task from working Ruby script on Ubuntu inside Windows10

Tags: ruby, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a Windows10 Ubuntu bash environment set up. It has a few rubygems installed (without docker, bundler, without rvm, and also this is not rails). The script is working fine when I run it manually from inside the Ubuntu terminal, in the user home folder ~/

Now my goal is create a Windows Scheduled Task using the **Task Scheduler** application, to run the script daily, like I would with a crontab in Unix.

The **action** in this Scheduled Task is the challenge. In testing manually from the Windows CMD prompt, I got as far as:

```
C:\>C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "ruby ~/myscript.rb"
```

That fails  :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /home/lam/ruby/remind_prepare_dad_before_iterative_ends.rb:15:in `<main>'
    1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- tiny_tds (LoadError)
```

Above error tells me it cannot find my gem, TinyTDS. What do I add to the command line to make it find my gems?

Comment: I used gem install, so with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072070/how-can-i-find-where-gem-files-are-installed/19072136 I could reference the INSTALLATION directory if i knew how.

Answer (score 1):

I found a crude workaround for my own problem: just install the gem from the same command line:

```
C:\>C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "sudo gem install tiny_tds"
```

I had to re-install a few more gems I use in the same way.

After this, I put in a -C argument to start ruby in the right directory, like so:

```
C:\>C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "ruby -C ~/ruby myscript.rb"
```

works like a charm.
I suppose now I have duplicated gems floating in spaces on the machine, but we will address that issue if it ever becomes a problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try `bundle exec ruby ~/myscript.rb`

Comment: yeah, make that "without docker, without rvm, and also this is not rails, and without bundler"

Comment: If you have a Gemfile using `bundle` will properly load the gems, if not then you have to install your dependencies globally and it should work.

EDIT: Also, validate your  `$PATH` in a bash session.

Comment: can you be more specific how to validate? i.e. what do I type and what should I expect?